# Save all skipped records and send those in a mail in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am new to spring batch and I have come across a scenario, where I have declared one exception in skippable exception, to skip the invalid records detected in item processor. Could you please help me with some possible way through which I can keep track of the all skipped records during the entire job run and at the end using job execution listener or some other way send a mail of all those skipped records.
Any suggestions would help.

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>springbatch.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>


    <!-- ItemReader which reads from database and returns the row mapped by 
        rowMapper -->
    <bean id="databaseItemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="sql" value="SELECT * FROM employee" />

        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.sample.springbatch.jdbc.EmployeeRowMapper" />
        </property>

    </bean>


    <!-- ItemWriter writes a line into output flat file -->
    <bean id="databaseItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[        
                    insert into actemployee(empId, firstName, lastName,additionalInfo) 
                    values (?, ?, ?, ?)
                ]]>
            </value>
        </property>

        <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
            <bean class="com.sample.springbatch.jdbc.EmployeePreparedStatementSetter" />
        </property>

    </bean>




    <!-- Optional ItemProcessor to perform business logic/filtering on the input 
        records -->
    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.sample.springbatch.EmployeeItemProcessor">
        <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step will need a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


    <bean id="recordSkipListener" class="com.sample.springbatch.RecordSkipListener" />

    <!-- Actual Job -->
    <batch:job id="employeeToActiveEmployee">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="databaseItemReader" writer="databaseItemWriter"
                    processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" skip-limit="500">
                    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                        <batch:include
                            class="javax.validation.ValidationException" />
                    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>

            </batch:tasklet>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="recordSkipListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>


    <!-- Email API bean configuarion -->
</beans>


Processor.java
        public class EmployeeItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Employee, ActiveEmployee> {

    private Validator validator;

    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }

    public void setValidator(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public ActiveEmployee process(Employee employee) throws Exception {
        BindingResult results = BindAndValidate(employee);
        if (results.hasErrors()) {
            buildValidationException(results);
        }
        System.out.println("Processing employee object:" + employee);
        ActiveEmployee activeEmployee = new ActiveEmployee(employee.getEmpId(), employee.getFirstName(),
                employee.getLastName(), "This is additional info");
        return activeEmployee;

    }

    private BindingResult BindAndValidate(Employee employee) {
        DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(employee);
        binder.setValidator(validator);
        binder.validate();
        return binder.getBindingResult();

    }

    private void buildValidationException(BindingResult results) {
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        for (ObjectError error : results.getAllErrors()) {
            msg.append("-*-*-*- \n" + error.toString() + "-*-*-*- \n");
        }
        throw new ValidationException(msg.toString());
    }

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you read the tag info of [tag:batch-file]? I assume not as you would know it is related to Windows otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `SkipListener` to write the skipped records to a file, then a `StepExecutionListener` to send an email with the file once the step completes.

Comment: Hi Michael. This seems it would solve my problem. I will give it a try. Thanks for the help.